# Registering XML Schemas in Oracle - how to get rid of leftover objects

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

I tried to register a schema in Oracle the other day to validate an XML document. The code I used was fairly simple:

```
dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(schemaURL => 'http://www.myCompany.com/schema',
                              schemaDoc => :schemaCLOB);
```

At first, everything seemed to work well, as far as validation goes. I noticed though, that there were dozens of new database objects: tables, triggers and types (a few dowsn tables and triggers, but probably many hundreds of types). 
I tried to delete the schema like this:

```
dbms_xmlschema.deleteSchema(schemaURL => 'http://www.myCompany.ca/schema',
                            delete_option => dbms_xmlschema.DELETE_INVALIDATE);
```

That de-registered the schema, but all of the objects were left behind.

I RTFM'd a little too late and discovered that the extra objects were created by leaving default values in the call to registerSchema, so I realized I would have to manually remove the extra objects.

Now when I try to remove the objects, Oracle tells me they don't exist. I can't select from them and my IDE (PL/SQL Developer) shows them as being invalid (a little red "X" beside them). I also can't find any info on these tables in `all_tables`. How do I get rid of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was: restored from previous day's backup. In the future, I'll be setting `gentables` and `gentypes` to `FALSE` ALWAYS, and delete with DELETE_CASCADE_FORCE. Anything doesn't work with that, I'll probably post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something obvious but looking at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlsch.htm#CHDEHIIF) could you not use the DELETE_CASCADE or DELETE_CASCADE_FORCE options?

Comment: In theory, yes, and that's probably what I'll do going forward (as well as use FALSE for gentables and gentypes).

I tried running my delete script and tried both of these options. It ran for over an hour (close to 2 I think) and the DBA just told me now to kill it and he'll see if he can purge these things.

Comment: Got access to metalink? If so check to see if you are affected by:

Bug 8498273: DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA HANGS FOREVER

or 

Bug 3581743: DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA FAILED LEAVING SCHEMA OBJECTS THAT CAN'T BE DELETED

Comment: As Marco has said it's Oracle's support site. Unfortunately due to clause(s) in the metalink contract I'm not allowed to post more details of the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Metalink is Oracle's support site (http://support.oracle.com) but you would need a customer support ID(entifier) to enter the protected site.

If on 11g use DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.PURGESCHEMA to get rid of the objects. If on 10gRx use

`dbms_xmlschema.deleteSchema(schemaURL => 'http://www.myCompany.ca/schema',
                            delete_option => dbms_xmlschema.DELETE_CASCADE_FORCE);`

or

`dbms_xmlschema.deleteSchema('http://www.myCompany.ca/schema',4);`

If that doesn't help bounce the database after using force delete and try again. If that doesn't help, delete the schema via a delete statement based on user_xml_schemas (last option is not supported).

Comment: We're on 10.2g here. Most likely we will restore from the backup for my schema from Monday (no major losses if I do).

I'm not even sure where I would delete the schema from if I were to do it manually, based on user_xml_schemas.